# What is the best way to tell the compiler to differentiate between two types which hold the same kind of data

Tags: c++

Suppose we have two types which are basically `int`s:

```
alias UserID = int;
alias ItemID = int;
```

And suppose we have two functions which take arguments of the two types:

```
void add_user(UserID id) { std::cout << "Adding user with id " << id << '\n'; }
void add_item(ItemID id) { std::cout << "Adding item with id " << id << '\n'; }
```

The problem is that we can do:

```
UserID uid {5};
add_item(uid);
```

And the compiler will not be able to protect me from passing the wrong type because both types alias the same underlying type.

What is the least boilerplate I need to add to make the compiler differentiate between the two types?

My current solution is to define the types as structs like this:

```
struct UserID
{
  int val;
  operator int() { return val; }
};

struct ItemID
{
  int val;
  operator int() { return val; }
};
```

The `operator int()` is to allow for an implicit conversion to the base type.

One problem with this approach is that sometimes I need to do arithmetic operations on the types, like for example:

```
UserID uid {5};
++uid;
```

Another problem is when these types are passed to a template and a template-argument deduction takes place where the correct type to deduce is `int` but the compiler is not able to see through the conversion operator.

I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution where both types would seamlessly convert to their base type when the base type is required but would still be different when the wrapping type is required.
What I want is the following:

```
add_user(UserID{1}); //compiles
add_item(ItemID{2}); //compiles
add_user(ItemID{3}); //doesn't compile
UserID uid = UserID{4} + 1; //compiles
++uid; //compiles
UserID uid2 = ItemID{5} + 1; //doesn't compile
```

By 'the least boilerplate' I mean the total boilerplate code I need to write both in the definition of the types as well as in the user code.

Comment: boost has a `STRONG_TYPEDEF`

Comment: This feels more like a user-problem: If the users of your functions and types calls the wrong functions, then it's their problem not yours. If you use the standard library wrong you have undefined behavior, it's the same of your users using your API wrong.

Comment: *"Suppose we have two types which are basically ints:"*. Those are not new types, but just aliases. which is your problem. as suggested, you need strong typedef (which is not native, but which are provided by some libraries).

Comment: btw, do you really need integer arithmetics on uids? imho `++uid` with simple integer arithmetics looks a little odd. For example integer ++ has no way to ensure that the uid is unique, while that is straightforward with a `uid.get_next_uid()`. Maybe your `UserID` is really not an `int`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'd like to shift the burden of type checking from the users to the compiler. It's the compiler's job to make sure we're not calling a function with the wrong argument types.

Comment: I often use `enum class` for this. It forces you to make explicit conversions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use "shadow types" (they have names but no definition) and a template (or use some "strong typedef" library):

```
template <typename>
class Id
{
    int val;
    operator int() const { return val; }
};

using UserID = Id<struct user_tag_>;
using ItemID = Id<struct item_tag_>;
```

And you should provide operator overloads for the operations that make sense - you most likely don't want to divide or multiply these IDs by anything.

Comment: I've used this pattern.  It works well.  Always a bit startling to realize the "dummy" `struct tag` template parameter only needs to be declared (and can be declared in place, as done here), and doesn't need to be defined anywhere.  I also have used and like Galik's `enum class` suggestion.

Comment: If it's a single definition of the class it's not a problem to add operations to it. I was concerned about code repetition in my original solution.
I like the fact that you can declare the tags internally into the template instantiation. That looks like the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should use some ready library, here is an example of [NamedType](https://github.com/joboccara/NamedType):

```cpp
#include <NamedType/named_type.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using UserID = fluent::NamedType<int, struct UserIDTag, fluent::PreIncrementable, fluent::Addable, fluent::Printable>;
using ItemID = fluent::NamedType<int, struct ItemIDTag, fluent::PreIncrementable, fluent::Addable, fluent::Printable>;

void add_user(UserID id) { std::cout << "Adding user with id " << id << '\n'; }
void add_item(ItemID id) { std::cout << "Adding item with id " << id << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    UserID uid { 5 };
    // add_item(uid); // fails to compile
    add_user(uid);

    add_user(UserID { 1 }); // compiles
    add_item(ItemID { 2 }); // compiles
    // add_user(ItemID { 3 }); // doesn't compile
    // UserID uid2 = UserID { 4 } + 1; // should compile - feature not supported
    ++uid; // compiles
    // UserID uid2 = ItemID { 5 } + 1; // doesn't compile

    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qhb65T9oz). Cool godbolt supports that library :).